# Como hacer que el array tenga el tamaño justo

Tags: java

Tengo una función en la cual en los parámetros tengo una `letraBuscada` que puede ser desde la **a** hasta la **z**

En caso de que encuentre un nombre del `String orig` crear otro `array` metiéndole ese nombre.

1º Hacer que el nuevo `array` el tamaño justo para que quepan cada nombre en cada posición que ni le falte ni le sobre.

este es la función:

```
public static String[] empiezaPor(char buscada,String []orig){

    Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
    String [] arrayRelleno;

    arrayRelleno=new String[orig.length];
    String letraBuscada=Character.toString(buscada);
    int capacidad=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < orig.length; i++) {
        //to do hacer variable con if para que si no encuentra ninguna palabra que el valor de null
        if (orig[i].startsWith(letraBuscada)) {
            arrayRelleno[i]=orig[i];
             capacidad=1;

        }




    }

    if (capacidad==0) {
            return null;
        }
    return arrayRelleno;
}
```

Comment: Podrías mostrar un ejemplo? No acabo de entender tu problema.

Comment: Casi lo tienes, no? Te quedaría crear un nuevo array de tamaño `capacidad` y copiar ahí las cadenas de `arrayRelleno` para retornar un array del tamaño justo. ¿No es eso?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando no se sabe el tamaño que va a tener un array se suele usar `ArrayList`, en el caso que te decidas a usarlo el codigo te quedaria algo asi:

```
public static List<String> empiezaPor(char buscada, String[] orig) {
    List<String> arrayRelleno = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < orig.length; i++) {
        if (orig[i].charAt(0) == buscada) { // charAt() devuelve el char de la posicion indicada
            arrayRelleno.add(orig[i]);
        }
    }

    return arrayRelleno;
}
```